# Flutter CupertinoContextMenu on LongPressAnimation going behind the screen

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to add CupertinoContextMenu to CupertinoListTile in flutter App, and when i long press on my item, some part of it just gone behind the screen. How I can fix this or just decrease scale animation.

[Video on Youtube, showing my case](https://youtu.be/ShuuSETYsiE)

Here's my code

```
    return CupertinoContextMenu(
  actions: [
    CupertinoContextMenuAction(
      child: const Text('Edit'),
      onPressed: () {
        //TODO: Handle the edit action
      },
    ),
    CupertinoContextMenuAction(
      child: const Text('Show'),
      onPressed: () {
        //TODO: Handle the show action
      },
    ),
  ],
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: CupertinoListTile(
      backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 16),
      title: Text(event.name, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
      subtitle: Text(event.formattedDate, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
      trailing: const CupertinoListTileChevron(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That animation provided by CupertinoContextMenu by default. I guess it's hard to change that.
for now -> if you don't want that your title and subtitle should not hide behind the screen. Add some padding at the left of title and subtitle.

```
 const CupertinoListTile(
                backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 16),
                title: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "name",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "formatted date",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: CupertinoListTileChevron(),
              ),
```

Comment: Yep, I thought that will be hard to change. Thanks for your answer but it still looks ugly when the container with box shadow just go behind the screen

Comment: yep, it's ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

You may already have got the solution but this response may help others.

So there is a really helpful package which does the works very smoothly. The package is `focused_menu`

just add this package in you `yaml` file manually,

```
dependencies:
  focused_menu: ^lattest_version
```

or just run this command to add

```
flutter pub add focused_menu
```

`import` this package in your dart file

```
import 'package:focused_menu/focused_menu.dart';
```

Now you can just wrap your widget inside `FocusedMenuHolder`

```
FocusedMenuHolder(
  onPressed: () => debugPrint('Do something'),
  openWithTap: true, // By default menu appears on long press
  menuItems: [
    FocusedMenuItem(
      title: const Text('Copy'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      trailingIcon: const Icon(Icons.copy),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
  child: Container(), // Your widget
);
```

You can go through the package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu)